# how to handle incoming URL request using only browser js?

Tags: javascript

I want to get information from URL.

Example: `mywesite.com/#base64text`

How to get incoming request using browser js. Which function to use in js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is extract the data after the hashtag symbol, then just use `.split()` with `location.href` like this:

```
const data = location.href.split('#', 2)[1];
```

If you need to go a step further and store JS objects in the URL, then you should use base64 encoded JSON. To generate encoded data and put it in the URL, just use `JSON.stringify()` and `atob()`:

```
const obj = {
  name: 'Bob',
  age: 30,
};

location.href += '#' + btoa(JSON.stringify(obj));
// the page will now reload with the data stored in the URL
```

Then, to decode that data, use `atob()` and `JSON.parse()`:

```
const urlData = location.href.split('#', 2)[1];
const data = urlData ? JSON.parse(atob(urlData)) : null;
console.log(data);
// returns any data stored in URL, or null
```

Comment: ey what happens if there's several hashtags? `foo.com#bla#bla` - it should be ```location.href.split('#', 2)[1];```

Comment: @hanshenrik Good call, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I think it would be much more convenient to just create a [URL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) interface. It has all the methods you need to work with it.

Comment: @icecub Possibly, however, it wouldn't really make the code any shorter. Also, I'd guess that creating a whole `URL` object would add some overhead just to access a single property.

Comment: @hanshenrik Oops, I forgot to edit that bit. Thanks!

Comment: True, it obviously depends on what you want to do with it. No reason to hire a truck to move a single bag of sand

Comment: `location.hash`